# docker-compose cannot find package

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, govendor

I'm writing a simple app in GO and I have this folder structure

[image]

The docker-compose.yml file content is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: rethinkdb:latest
    ports:
      - "38080:8080"
      - "38015:28015"
      - "39015:29015"
  api:
    image: golang:1.8-alpine
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/test_server/
    working_dir: /go/src/test_server
    command: go run server.go
    container_name: test_server
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    links:
      - db
    tty: true
```

Everytime I run docker-compose up I receive this error message:

> test_server | controllers/users.go:4:3: cannot find package
>   "_/go/src/test_server/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
>   test_server |
>   /usr/local/go/src/_/go/src/test_server/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin
>   (from $GOROOT) test_server |
>   /go/src/_/go/src/test_server/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from
>   $GOPATH)

It's referring to the controllers package. I'm using github.com/kardianos/govendor to vendor my packages. Do you know what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

After many hours I finally could fix it.
Resulted that I was using a docker golang version that it doesn't have git included. I should use golang:1.8

I modified my Dockerfile like this and now it works like a charm

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go install -v

CMD ["app"]
```

Comment: It gives error : go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd, do you have any idea how to solve this too ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell go where find the packages:

```
api:
  ...
  environment:
    - GOPATH=/go/src/test_server
```

Or have a Dockerfile with the proper packages installed (recommended)

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work, the error message now is this:
test_server | ers/users.go:4:3: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
test_server |   /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
test_server |   /go/src/test_server/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)

I tried with Dockerfile as well because I though it's a more elegant solution, but everytime I build it, I get the error:


This is the Dockerfile content:
FROM golang:1.8-alpine
RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
EXPOSE 8085

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your updated code is running go install, not go run which your old code was running.

You needed to install the extra golang packages into the vendor directory that you are calling from your app.